# How do I clean out dust in the fans of my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hardware

How do I clean out the dust in the fans of my MacBook Pro? (I'm perfectly comfortable with opening my MacBook Pro up (Unibody 2008 edition with removable battery cover), but I'm not exactly sure how I would carry out the dust-cleaning procedure.

Recently my lower left part (In typing perspective) of my MacBook Pro had a really odd sound coming from it. I remember seeing a fan on that part and had saw lots of dust on it, but never did anything much about it.

Would I use my fingers to scrape out the dust in the fans? Or a can of compressed air? (Wouldn't that be counterproductive? I would be blowing all the dust into the MacBook Pro/the unibody case itself/onto the other components on the motherboard?)

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

At least, you will be able to have access to your fan without breaking your MacBook Pro. iFixit has a step by step [procedure](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repair/Installing-MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-Unibody-Late-2008-and-Early-2009-Right-Fan/828/1) that you can follow to take off the parts of your computer so that you have access to the fans.

As far as I'm concerned, I would use a can of compressed air.

Answer (score 1):

I used the [IFixit guide that OGenius linked](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repair/Installing-MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-Unibody-Late-2008-and-Early-2009-Right-Fan/828/1) to. I had a small piece of paper stuck. I did not actually have to remove the fans, I just opened the laptop, blew a bit and used a vacuum cleaner a bit too.